# Remove CloudFlare sript from header?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cloudflare, rocketscript

I'm currently modify a site left from the previous developer. I'm working to modify some javascript. However, all of my changes only works in my localhost site, and not the staging site. I viewed the source code on browsers and see those script links has changed to something like this `<script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc='...'></script>` which I believe my updated JS codes won't work because of that.

I also see the cloudflare cdn code above it as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"204f23173dc3b0ee3fe57272b30ddbf2",petok:"6d99c6da0f9c5af0b780fc54f705ae1b6732742a-1439571640-1800",betok:"1b5c428c2c19f5473b41af6d945e42424041cb79-1439571640-120",zone:"hagarstage.com",rocket:"a",apps:{}}];document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=e9627cd26a/cloudflare.min.js"><'+'\/script>');}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
```

But my localhost site does not have this kind of script loading.

I explored all the plugins and there is no cloudflare related plugins installed.
I believe that my codes will take effect once I have removed this script.

I see the link here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cloudflare-code-left-after-uninstalling. However, no one answered it. So is there any way to completely remove this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would only insert that JavaScript if the site was on the CloudFlare network in some way (signed up directly/through a hosting partner). It looks like Rocket Loader is turned on & turning on optional performance features (like Rocket Loader) or apps would inject JavaScript on your site that are running through the proxy (that's why you see a difference checking your server directly).

Comment: Hi demoncloudflare. The think that I'm afraid of is that he made a configuration at CloudFlare with his account. Is that possible to do that?

Comment: Hi,

It is possible that is the case here. The only way to remove it would be to turn off the optional apps and features in the account. The header gets added by us, so there's no way to remove it from the page while our proxy is running over a record.

Comment: Hi demoncloudflare, is there any chance I can get rid of this config without logging in to the account? I contacted the previous developer and he forgot the credential he made to register with CF

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you have a cache plugin on the staging server that uses CloudFlare as it's CDN?

Comment: Hello Abby, thanks for getting back to me. There is no cache plugin installed in the website, but there is a CloudFlare supper cache section found in the cPanel

Comment: That's probably it then - if you turn that off, does the javascript go away?

Comment: Hi Abby, sorry for the lateness. Actually, it's the default feature provided in cPanel, and there's no configuration from there